# failed using bootstrap-carousel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tried to view the following htm, but I don't get the same result as in

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html - **carousel**

js/Default.js:

```
 $(function () {
    //    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 2000 })

        $('#myCarousel').carousel()
            });
```

markup:

```
    <head>
        <link href="Resources/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Example carousel</h2>
        <p>Watch the slideshow below.</p>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="Images/Browser/add.JPG" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                            elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                            vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/Browser/delete.JPG" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                            elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                            vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="Images/Browser/rename.JPG" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                            elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                            vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
        <script src="Resources/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Resources/Scripts/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The html you pasted looks like it matches the requirements for the carousel plugin. The only thing I don't see that is probably your issue: You need to include jquery, the main bootstrap.js as well as the bootstrap-carousel.js files.

Comment: They are all imported the the bottom of the <body>

Comment: When you say that you don't get the same result as in the demo, what do you get? Something different or an error?
Perhaps if you try including the whole bootstrap.js file, instead of the carousel only?

Comment: Do you get something like this? I notice that it doesn't scroll when I copy yours over...http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/5BMr8/2/

Comment: @periklis I get all the 3 steps (3 photos + 3 subtitbles) as a vertical list of items. i don't this there is one common bootstrap.js

Comment: @dsummersl I get something totally different: I get all the 3 steps (3 photos + 3 subtitbles) as a vertical list of items.

Comment: If you are using the latest version of bootstrap, 2.0, and download from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/, you'll see that it includes a cumulative .js file

Comment: @periklis thanks I'll update the fiddle. bummer - but jsfiddle is down!

Comment: @elad if you are only getting the list its likely you aren't actually including the css file. double check that its actually loading. Even if your javascript weren't working the layout should be formatted correctly by the bootstrap css include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above if you are only seeing an unformatted list of items that bear no ressemblence to the slide show UI for bootstrap then you are probably not referencing the bootstrap CSS file (maybe you have the wrong URL). Use the 'Web Inspector' or 'Developer Tools' in your browser to make sure that the JS and CSS files you are including are actually being found (you'll see red text if not!).

To help you implement this feature I've created a minimimal working jsfiddle example using your original text:

[example implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/5BMr8/5/)

The basic steps required to get the carousel working are:

1. Format your html correctly with the `carousel`, `carousel-inner`, and `item` classes (which you did do correctly).
2. Include the bootstrap.css file.
3. Include the following javascript files: jquery, bootstrap-transition, bootstrap-carousel

---

Comment: How can I make the gray subtitles + photos fit in meduimed-sized (not all screen) and centered div? I tried to put inside a div with proprer height and width - but it's still all over the screen width

Comment: I want it to appear like the example here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html (under carousel)

Comment: My first guess is that you should use the bootstrap spanX classes - but I'm not sure exactly what you're going for. Could you modify the jsfiddle and send me a link so I have a better idea of what you are going for?

Comment: i did now. Was it saved on jsfiddle? I want the carousel to be in the center of the page and not for the whole screen width.

Comment: Here I aligned the .carousel in the center (80%) - is that what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/dsummersl/5BMr8/14/