# Bootstrap Carousel Interval False Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've installed Twitter Bootstrap-Carousel on a site and I wanted to be able to use it to step through panes of a module, however, setting interval to false is not working. If I give it an interval, it will step through just fine as scheduled, but as false I am unable to use the controls to step through the slides. I am selecting the container by ID rather than $('.carousel') so I don't know if that has anything to do with it. Is there another module needed that gives the interval false functionality?

A brief example of my html is:

```
    <div class="carousel" id="module-rotator">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">foo</div>
            <div class="item">bar</div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#module-rotator" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#module-rotator" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
```

and I initialize the carousel with this:

```
$('#module-rotator').carousel({ interval: false });
```

I am using bootstrap-carousel.js v2.0.3

Comment: can you show the code you are using?  Also make sure you're using the latest version of bootstrap (v2.0.3 as of now)

Comment: Okay, I've added the samples above.

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug in the Bootstrap Carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using similar code to yours and everything works as expected.  The only differences are;

- I'm using the complete bootstrap.js (v2.0.3) (so not individual bootstrap js files)
- I also have the "slide" class next to the "carousel" class - without this the divs would still change, just not slide.

After reading the answer to a similar question [failed using bootstrap-carousel.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227416/failed-using-bootstrap-carousel-js) I would suspect you'll also need to include bootstrap-transition.js before the bootstrap-carousel.js

I suggest using the complete bootstrap.js file just to verify it works, then play around with the individual js files.

Comment: I had both bootstrap and bootstrap-carousel, I removed bootstrap-carousel and it's still not working. I also verified that the CDN I was using was 1.7.2 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js).