# How to stop bootstrap carousel from cycling in a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Ok...here is my code...right now....when the page loads the first image does not move...but once the visitor selects the next image and then stops selecting images...the carousel starts to autocycle at it's default 5secs per image. I DON'T want the carousel to auto cycle at all.
I want a site visitor to only be able to move the images when they click the next button.

What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <nav class="navbar-inner">



      </nav>
    </header>
    </div>

    <div id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
              <!-- yeild goes here -->
              <h1><%= image_tag "logo.png", :title => "Home", :class => "logo" %></h1>
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="active item"><%= image_tag "home_1.jpg", :title => "title", :class => "class" %></div>
                  <div class="item"><%= image_tag "home_2.jpg", :title => "title", :class => "class" %></div>
                  <div class="item"><%= image_tag "home_3.jpg", :title => "title", :class => "class" %></div>
                  <div class="item"><%= image_tag "home_4.jpg", :title => "title", :class => "class" %></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
              </div>
              <!-- yeild ends here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!--! end of .container -->
    </div> <!--! end of #main -->
    <div class="container">
      <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"><!--! TODO footer goes here -->
        <nav class="navbar-inner">



        </nav>
      </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look at the Bootstrap docs for how to configure the carousel?

Comment: The *Rails* source code does little to help when it should be page source, and if you provide a http://jsfiddle.net demo, *that would help*. As I said above, have you consulted the docs? There's only three or four options, and `pause` is the only one that might be guilty unless what you're not showing us has the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'VE consulted the docs. There is no other way to even begin using bootstrap without it. I am using almost the exact code FROM the docs. I think the docs are wrong somehow or they are missing a critical step.....like so many other docs on the internet.

Comment: Then consult the source.

Comment: check out this link...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669430/bootstrap-carousel-interval-false-not-working